# Condition at Inverse function

Tags: inverse

My goal is to get inverse of -Log[1 - x]. But the result shows conditional expression.
Could I know Why the condition  -[Pi] <= Im[y] < [Pi] shows? There wass no assumption at variable y.

```
u[x_] := -Log[1 - x]

x /. Solve[y == u[x], x][[1]]
```

And the result showed,

```
ConditionalExpression[1 - E^-y, -\[Pi] <= Im[y] < \[Pi]]
```

Comment: Since `x` or `y` can be a complex number. `InverseFunction[u]`

Comment: Thank you for reply. but I wonder How to remove the conditions(= Is there a way to assume x and y as Real at Mathmatica for this case?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way ...

```
u[x_] := -Log[1 - x]

Assuming[{Element[x, Reals], Element[y, Reals]}, x /. Solve[y == u[x], x][[1]]]
```

yields

```
1 - E^-y
```